# prove that lim(2(b_n)^3+a_n/(2n))=2 by check the definition of limit of sequence

Tags: limits

Let {a_n} and {b_n} be two sequences of real numbers such that both {a_n} and {b_n} converge to 1. Prove that lim(2(b_n)^3+a_n/(2n))=2 by checking the **definition of limit of sequence**
∀ε>0,∃K∈N such that n≥K⇒|2(b_n)^3+(a_n/2n)-2|<ε

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first look it seems that $
\frac {a_n}n\to 0$ so we want to make it small, and the rest should go to 2.

Let us properly write this.

---

Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $0<r<1$ be be fixed at a later stage.

- $a_n$ is bounded: we can find a $K$ such as
  $$
  n>K\implies 1-\frac 12 \le a_n \le 1+\frac 12 \implies |a_n| \le \frac 32.
  $$
- $b_n\to 1$: we can then assume
  $$
  n>K_r\ge K \implies |b_n-1|\le r
  \\ \implies |b_n|\le 1+|b_n-1| \le 1+r\le 2.
  $$
- Now, $2b_n^3+a_n/2n - 2 = 2[b_n^3 -1] + a_n/2n $.
  We already know that $|a_n/2n| < 3/4n$.
  $$
  n>K_r\implies|b_n^3 -1| = |b_n - 1||b_n^2 + b_n + 1| \le
  7r;
  \\
  n>K_r\implies\left|2b_n^3+\frac{a_n}{2n} - 2\right|
  \le 2|b_n^3 -1| +\left|\frac{a_n}{2n}
  \right| \le 14r + \frac 3{4K_r}
  $$

Now, let us make the choice
$$
r = \frac\epsilon {28};
\\
K' = \max\left(\frac 3{4\epsilon}, K_r\right).
$$
Eventually,
$$
n>K'\implies\left|2b_n^3+\frac{a_n}{2n} - 2\right|
\le \frac \epsilon 2 + \frac \epsilon 2 = \epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_n,b_n \to 1$. Given $\varepsilon>0$

\begin{align}\left|2(b_n)^3+(a_n/2n) -2\right|\le 2|b_n^3-1|+\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{a_n}{n} \right|=2|b_n-1||b_n^2+b_n+1|+\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{a_n}{n} \right|\\
\le2|b_n-1|(|b_n|^2+|b_n|+1)+ \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{a_n}{n} \right|\end{align}

Choose $n_0(1)$ such that  $|a_n-1|<1$ and $|b_n-1|< 1$ for all $n\ge n_0$, then we have $|b_n|<2$ and $|a_n|<2$. Thus

$$2|b_n-1|(|b_n|^2+|b_n|+|1|)+ \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{a_n}{n} \right|\le14|b_n-1|+\frac{1}{n}$$

Choose  $n_1(\varepsilon/2)\ge n_0(1)$ such that and $1/n_1<\varepsilon/2$ and since $b_n \to 1$, let choose $n_2(\varepsilon/28)\ge n_1(\varepsilon/2)$ such that $|b_n-1|< \varepsilon/28$ for all $n\ge n_2(\varepsilon/28)$. Hence

$$14|b_n-1|+\frac{1}{n}\le \varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$$

as desired.